# Get position of selected item...?

Tags: java, android, sql

I'm rather new to Android. Here's part of code:

```java
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
Note selectedName = adapter.getItem(position);
adapter.removeItem(selectedName);
```

As you see, position means selected item position. That's good. But I'd prefer long clicks:

```java
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch(item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.ctxmemu_delete:
** I need to use POSITION mentioned above! **
```

But in this method `getSelectedItemPosition` returns position -9995845834585 (or smth like that)
Or it gives error (can't move cursor to position - I use SQL in my app)

How can I get position from list properly?
P.S. sorry for my bad English :(

UPD:
I've added this to my SQL Adapter:

```java
public int getPosition(){
return cursor.getPosition();    }
```

and modified:

```java
case R.id.ctxmemu_delete:
int position = adapter.getPosition();
Note seln = adapter.getItem(position);
adapter.removeItem(seln);
return true;
```

for now it works...but I think it's so ugly...

Comment: Why don't you use a onListItemLongClick listener instead of going for the context menu ?

Comment: Kondra check my answer :) it should solve your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to understand it now..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use onListItemLongClick() instead of onListItemClick().

Comment: Will I need to inhabit superclass? (or smth like that)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a **`onListItemLongClick listener`** instead of going for the context menu ?

```
protected void onListItemLongClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
super.onListItemLongClick(l, v, position, id);
Note selectedName = adapter.getItem(position);
adapter.removeItem(selectedName);
}
```

Comment: I want to make my context menu (in future)

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { ... }
```

Since you are using [`ContextMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html) this is a little different from [`ItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

You can use **MenuInfo** for getting position in `ListView`

```
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = 
                         (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
```

Where it has `int` property `info.position` that returns position in the adapter for which the context menu was displayed.

**Note:** You can also have look at [`OnItemLongClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener.html) with works similar.